# How to order a query result by two columns with nulls last in one of the columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, case

I have the following table 'client'

```
ID|name|filecount
---------------------- 
1  Jim  7
2  Jane null
3  Mike 18
4  Jeff 12
5  Ann  null
6  Helen 22
```

I want to fetch all rows from this table `ordered by ID Desc`, with nulls in the column `filecount` ordered last.

So after the sorting I would like to get the following order:

```
ID|name  |filecount 
---------------------- 
6  Helen 22
4  Jeff  12
3  Mike  18
1  Jim   7
5  Ann   null
2  Jane  null
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
Select * from client order by id desc, (filecount > 0) nulls last
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `CASE` expression here:

```
SELECT *
FROM client
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN filecount IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    ID DESC;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by `filecount` first with differentiation between 0 and non-0 values only and then by `ID`:

```
select *
from client
order by case
        when filecount <> 0 then 0
        else 1
    end, ID desc
```

P.S.: Those are not `null`s, those are zeros. If they should be `null`s, then change this line:

```
when filecount <> 0 then 0
```

to:

```
when filecount is not null then 0
```

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake, they should be nulls. I corrected the question.